# How to use a function on a button which don't exist yet

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm sorry to bother you but I need advices. So here's my problem :

I've got a page which contains a button, let's call it BoutonA.

When I click on BoutonA, a second button is created, let's call it BoutonB.

I worked in Javascript on a Wordpress if that can helps you !

I want to launch a function when the BoutonB is clicked. The problem is when the script starts, BoutonB doesn't exist yet.
Here's a little schema, hope you enjoy my draw skills
[image: schema]

Here's are my tries :

```
while(document.body.contains(BoutonB)){

   openStream()
}
```

```
if (boutonB.length < 1) {

  console.log("don't work");
}
else {

  openStream()
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help ! 
I learn JS so if you have any advices, I'll take it !
Happy coding !

Comment: how are you creating BoutonB? You will need to add an onclick listener to it then.

Comment: In fact it's my BoutonA which creates BoutonB (it's a wordpress plugin..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can do like this, hope this answer will help you.

```
document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.id== 'button-b'){
          //do something
          openStream();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can it works with class ? :)

Comment: Yes it can work with class and other attributes as well 
for class will work like this e.target.className

Comment: like this : e.target.className = "classOfMyButton" ? I tried and it didn't worked :/

Comment: then please try this may be it will work e.target.classList.contains('class name of your button')

Comment: ```document.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if(e.target && e.target.classList.contains('edd-free-download-submit edd-submit button blue')){
          //do something
          console.log("yeet");
    }
}); ``` It didn't works too. Maybe you have an idea ?

Comment: You can check here its working https://js.do/YogeshShrimali/eventlistener

Comment: Thanks for your link, actually the problem is the button A generates Button B. :/

Comment: Can you share your previous code i will modify this?

Comment: The 1st HTML : 
```
<div class="edd_free_downloads_form_class">
<a class="button blue edd-submit edd-submit edd-free-download edd-free-download-single" href="#edd-free-download-modal" data-download-id="1655">Accéder au Webinar</a>     
</div>
```

The 2nd HTML generated by the 1st HTML : ```<button name="edd_free_download_submit" class="edd-free-download-submit edd-submit button blue"><span>Télécharger la ressource</span></button> ```

Comment: Hello @Anatole Please now check this link may be it will help you https://js.do/YogeshShrimali/eventlistener

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure but can't you link the function to the button? Instead of adding an event listener.

```
<button onclick="openStream()">Im button b</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately I can't because this button is generated with e a plugin. So I can't modify it :/ To use my function I add attribute on the button :)